# Convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin(n)\cdot\sin(1/n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I was doing math and I came across this series

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin n\cdot\sin\left(\dfrac1n\right)$$

I managed to prove that this series is convergent, but I was wondering what value the series converges to $?$
I've put it on Scientific workplace and got a value of around $0.92 $ But I have no idea how to get there.

Comment: Yeah since 1/n goes to 0 as n goes to infinity and sin(0)=0.

Comment: Are you asking about the series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin{(n)}\sin{(1/n)}\approx 0.9207$$or the limit of the associated summand?

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes im asking for the series which is 0.9207

Comment: I see no reason to suspect that $\sum \sin n \sin(1/n)$ has a closed form.

Answer (score 5):

The limit should be $0$.

An easy way to think about it is when n gets large, $\sin(\frac{1}{n})\approx \frac{1}{n}$. Then, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(n)\sin(\frac{1}{n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(n)}{n}=0$ because $\sin(n)$ is bounded and $n$ is unbounded.

Comment: @Matematleta the question was edited. The question I answered asked of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
0 
\leq |\sin n \cdot \sin \frac1n|
= |\sin n| \cdot |\sin \frac1n|
\leq |\sin \frac1n|
\to |\sin 0|
= |0|
= 0.
$$

Thus,
$$\sin n \cdot \sin\frac1n \to 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

You have a product of 2 sequences.  The first is bounded and the second has limit 0. So the product should be a sequence with limit 0.